# WebRTC - create a connection client-client from the server

Tags: javascript, html, server, client, webrtc

I'm trying to code a Voice-Call application using WebRTC. I know that I have to create the peer-to-peer connection to connect the two clients in order to start seeing each other in a webcam conference, BUT:

**Is there any way to let the server create and maintain the connection?**

Following [this guide](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) I know that one client has to offer and create a connection and the other has to "reply" in order the start a conversation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create socket events to send call accept/reject requests.
But first you need to setup server and client side p2p communication.
For webRTC server: [Licode webRTC Server](http://lynckia.com/licode/index.html)
And for ios cleint for Licode :
Visit: [Licode Erizo Client iOS](https://github.com/zevarito/Licode-ErizoClientIOS)

This solution is the only ope source solution available on web.
Best of luck.